# Is there an XSLT for manipulate a Json structure and his hierarchy?

Tags: json, xslt, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i have this Json from the backend, that doesn't manage a hierarchy in the query and i would like to order it with an xslt

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "result": [{
        "documentTypeId": 1,
        "name": "Contatto cliente",
        "description": "Contatto cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerContact",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 1,
        "phase": "presale",
        "registryRoleId": 1
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 2,
        "name": "Richiesta da cliente",
        "description": "Richiesta da cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerRequest",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 2,
        "phase": "sale",
        "registryRoleId": 1
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 3,
        "name": "Offerta a cliente",
        "description": "Offerta a cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerOffer",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 3,
        "phase": "sale",
        "registryRoleId": 1
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 4,
        "name": "Ordine da cliente",
        "description": "Ordine da cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerOrder",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 4,
        "phase": "sale",
        "registryRoleId": 1
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 5,
        "name": "Fornitura merce a cliente",
        "description": "Fornitura merce a cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerGoodsSupply",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 5,
        "phase": "sale",
        "registryRoleId": 2
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 6,
        "name": "Fornitura servizio a cliente",
        "description": "Fornitura servizio a cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerServicesSupply",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 6,
        "phase": "sale",
        "registryRoleId": 2
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 7,
        "name": "Fornitura consulenza a cliente",
        "description": "Fornitura consulenza a cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerConsultingSupply",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 7,
        "phase": "sale",
        "registryRoleId": 1
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 8,
        "name": "Fattura a cliente",
        "description": "Fattura a cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerInvoice",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 8,
        "phase": "sale",
        "registryRoleId": 1
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 9,
        "name": "Fattura finale",
        "description": "Fattura finale a cliente",
        "menuKey": "finalCustomerInvoice",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 9,
        "phase": "sale",
        "registryRoleId": 2
    }, {
        "documentTypeId": 11,
        "name": "Chiusura contatto cliente",
        "description": "Chiusura contatto cliente",
        "menuKey": "customerContactClose",
        "processId": 1,
        "eventId": 11,
        "phase": "presale",
        "registryRoleId": 1
    }]
}
```

I would like to group by "phase" ("presale" for first) and then order it by "documentTypeId" to have something like this :

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "result": [{
            "documentTypeId": 1,
            "name": "Contatto cliente",
            "description": "Contatto cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerContact",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 1,
            "phase": "presale",
            "registryRoleId": 1
        },
        {
            "documentTypeId": 11,
            "name": "Chiusura contatto cliente",
            "description": "Chiusura contatto cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerContactClose",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 11,
            "phase": "presale",
            "registryRoleId": 1
        },
        {
            "documentTypeId": 2,
            "name": "Richiesta da cliente",
            "description": "Richiesta da cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerRequest",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 2,
            "phase": "sale",
            "registryRoleId": 1
        }, {
            "documentTypeId": 3,
            "name": "Offerta a cliente",
            "description": "Offerta a cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerOffer",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 3,
            "phase": "sale",
            "registryRoleId": 1
        }, {
            "documentTypeId": 4,
            "name": "Ordine da cliente",
            "description": "Ordine da cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerOrder",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 4,
            "phase": "sale",
            "registryRoleId": 1
        }, {
            "documentTypeId": 5,
            "name": "Fornitura merce a cliente",
            "description": "Fornitura merce a cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerGoodsSupply",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 5,
            "phase": "sale",
            "registryRoleId": 2
        }, {
            "documentTypeId": 6,
            "name": "Fornitura servizio a cliente",
            "description": "Fornitura servizio a cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerServicesSupply",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 6,
            "phase": "sale",
            "registryRoleId": 2
        }, {
            "documentTypeId": 7,
            "name": "Fornitura consulenza a cliente",
            "description": "Fornitura consulenza a cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerConsultingSupply",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 7,
            "phase": "sale",
            "registryRoleId": 1
        }, {
            "documentTypeId": 8,
            "name": "Fattura a cliente",
            "description": "Fattura a cliente",
            "menuKey": "customerInvoice",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 8,
            "phase": "sale",
            "registryRoleId": 1
        }, {
            "documentTypeId": 9,
            "name": "Fattura finale",
            "description": "Fattura finale a cliente",
            "menuKey": "finalCustomerInvoice",
            "processId": 1,
            "eventId": 9,
            "phase": "sale",
            "registryRoleId": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I will use this XSLT in XSLT mediator in WSO2 ei.
Thank you
Alternatively, could i use a javascript code for this manipulation?

Comment: You do realize that the "X" in XSLT stands for "XML", not for "JSON"?

Comment: If WS02ei can use XSLT 3.0, then you could use the [json-to-xml](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-json-to-xml) function for this.

Comment: I know that the "X" stands for "XML", indeed i was thinking to trasform it in xml and then use the xslt.
But, there is a way to manage the structure without the passage to XML?

Comment: _"[is] there [...] a way to manage the structure without the passage to XML?"_ XSLT works with XML trees. If you want a transformation framework for JSON, then that's another question already asked.